# python 3.6.3. zlib compression

Tags: python-3.x, compression, zlib

I am trying to Compress a string in python 3.6.3 using zlib, but getting an error(TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str') , it was supposed to work on python  2.7- versions, here is my simple code:

```
import zlib
a='hellohellohelloheeloohegregrf'
b=zlib.compress(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import zlib
a='hellohellohelloheeloohegregrf'
b=zlib.compress(a.encode("utf-8"))
print(b)
```

Alternative:

```
import zlib
a= b'hellohellohelloheeloohegregrf'
b=zlib.compress(a)
print(b)
```

In `Python2.x` this string literal is called a `str` object but it's stored as `bytes`.

In `Python3.x` this string literal is a `str` object and its type is `Unicode`. So, one need to prefix it with `b` or use `.encode` to get `bytes` object.